# How do I resolve Error E108: No such variable: "b:eclim_tab_id" in textfmt plugin v3.0?

Tags: vimscript, plugin-eclim

I manually installed the `txtfmt` plugin ([Brett Stahlman's The Vim Highlighter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2208)) ver 3.0. After trying to run `:MakeTestPage`, I get the following error:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>36_MakeTestPage: line 21:     
MakeTestPage(): Error opening test page: E108: No such variable: "b:eclim_tab_id"
```

I have eclim installed (although it's not running now). I'd really like to keep my eclim, if possible.

I checked for solutions in README, in `:help txtfmt` and in google without any success.

I was wondering if anyone can at least tell me what I need to do to fix the above problem or at least how to approach it (I'm relatively new to vimscript).

Comment: Try running the plugin by itself without any other plugins. Does it still throw an error?

Comment: It's an alpha release. You should report that to the author. He can fix that pretty easily, I guess

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt - tried also the earlier release from 5 years ago (prior to alpha) and exact same error comes up.

Comment: @fruglemonkey - disabling all other plugins is not helping and error persisting.